# How to know the status of apache solr for daily indexed documents

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using apache solr 4.10.x. APache nutch is being used to to crawl and index documents. Now my crawler is running, I want to know how many documents are indexed on each iteration of nutch or per day.

Any idea or any tool provided by apache solr for this purpose?

Comment: Do you store an attribute like "indexed_date" or "date_created" alongside with your solr documents? Then you could just run a facet query ...

Comment: Yes I have a time stamp field. Then what factory query should I run?

Answer (score 1):

```
facet=true
facet.date=myDateField
facet.date.start=start_date
facet.date.end=end_date
facet.date.gap=+1MONTH(duration like +1DAY in your case).
```

append everything in your URL if you are using HTTP request with &.

Comment: I have a field tstamp in solr that has store property only and not indexed, Its value are like   "tstamp": "2015-03-05T04:57:54.032Z". Now how I can do the job

Answer (score 1):

You can hit a url with command=status
for example in my case it was 
qt=/dataimport&command=status

it gives you the status like committed or rollback or total documents processed...

for more info check at 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Check for "command"